# White space between picture in first row and green coloured cell in second row

Tags: html, html-table, whitespace

I have just recently picked up coding again for a newsletter and have encountered the notorious white space problem. However, I do not have any  in my rudimentary code and would appreciate if you could help getting rid of the white space between my banner in the first row and a green coloured second row.

[image: Snapshot with white [bar]

The code is as follows:

```
<table style="vertical-align: bottom; background-color: rgb(0, 136, 64); width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <a href="www.whatever.com"><img style="border: 0; width: 800px;" alt="Logo.jpg"></a>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15px;">31 July 2012</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How to get rid of the white space between the cells?

Comment: You do realize that your `<a>` there is not inside a table cell? Try fixing your syntax first.

Answer (score 0):

Your first TR is missing a TD. This may fix it:

```
<table style="vertical-align: bottom; background-color: rgb(0, 136, 64); width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
        <tr><td style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"><a href="www.whatever.com" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><img style="border: 0; margin: 0; width: 800px;" alt="Logo.jpg"></a></td></tr>   
        <tr><td style="text-align: right; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-right: 15px;">31 July 2012</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```